# How to set default date for the calender control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, ado.net, calendar-control

How to set Calender Control to 1 week past from the current date in asp.net web application to get data from Database to Gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pageload(or whereever need in event life cycle), write the following snippet: (Assuming the id of the calender control to be:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    calenderSagar.SelectedDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-8);
    }
```